# What is this traffsecurity.xyz site?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for a feature on whatsapp and came across this google result: http://traffsecurity.xyz/questions/tagged/whatsapp

On investigating, it seems to be a mirror of what's on superuser.com?

NIC whois info shows as private

Comment: *traf* backwards is *fart*.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Its an *exact* duplicate of our site and its something that you *should* report so that action can be taken.

As per the [official meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do) post on the topic

> The site is a proxy. Whatever the purpose of the site actually is, malicious or not, proxies represent a serious security threat to our site. Sometimes they even start showing up in Google results and users click on them not realizing that they aren't actually on Stack Overflow. Users get confused, or try to log in and accidentally send sensitive information to a third-party service.

And ... well, I double checked to make sure I was on the real site on other tabs, so clearly its confusing.

Please report it with the 'contact us' link, with relevant details like how you found the clone site so the community team (and maybe legal) can help handle the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've done as you suggested

Comment: Interestingly the login page is offline. :D

Comment: @EuriPinhollow Captchas aren't set up either.

Comment: and the "ask a question" page does not work.

Comment: .... sounds like they need a meta site...